# displaying wrong duplicated row numbers

Tags: powershell

I am preparing PowerShell script to Output the rows to the console if the priority is duplicated from the previous (upper) rules. I have prepared and tested below powershell code but it is displaying not exact rows which is having duplicate values. can some one please help to fix this issue.

```
Code:
# Load the Excel file
$designSheet = " /home/lokeshdir/designsheet.xlsx"
$excel = Import-Excel -Path $designSheet
# Iterate through the rows and check for duplicated priorities
for ($i = 1; $i -lt $excel.Count; $i++) {
    $currentRow = $excel[$i]
    $currentPriority = $currentRow.Priority

    $previousRow = $excel[$i - 1]
    $previousPriority = $previousRow.Priority

    if ($currentPriority -eq $previousPriority) {
        Write-Host "Row $($i + 1) has a duplicated priority value."
        # Output additional information or actions if needed
    }
}

Output:
PS /home/lokeshdir> ./NSGRulesvalidation.ps1 
Row 11 has a duplicated priority value.
Row 18 has a duplicated priority value.
PS /home/lokeshdir>
```

Below is the screenshot for reference:
[image]

The green color box referred to the original value and red color referred as duplicated  after comparing with Direction (inbound/outbound).

Comment: Sounds like `Group-Object` on the property `Priority` is better suited for what you want to accomplish

Comment: As it stands, your code is only comparing the current row to the immediately previous row, not to *all* previous rows, so it will only find duplicates that are next to each other (and as an aside, your sample also doesn't do a check for the Direction in your description).

Comment: The easiest way to remember -all- previous priority values would be with a hash. `Group-Object` does that for you.

Comment: Thank you SantiagoSquarzon, mclayton and lit for your quick response. if you can share any sample code by using Group-Object then it will be helpful for me so that I can test it for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you the list of rows that contain duplicate Priority / Direction pairs...

```
$data = @"
Priority,Name,Direction
10,ad-rule,Inbound
20,ftp-rule,Inbound
30,dummy-rule,Inbound
10,ad-rule-10,Inbound
40,ad-rule,Inbound
50,ad-rule-50,Inbound
60,ad-rule-60,Inbound
:,:,Inbound
:,:,Inbound
990,,Inbound
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

# get the *sets* of duplicate items
#   foreach-object - create a new list of objects with a row number associated with each item
#   group-object   - group rows into sets base on Priority and Direction
#   where-object   - only keep sets that have more than one item in them (i.e. duplicates)
$duplicates = $data `
    | foreach-object `
        -begin   { $row = 2 } `
        -process {
            [pscustomobject] @{
                "Row"       = $row
                "Priority"  = $_.Priority
                "Name"      = $_.Name
                "Direction" = $_.Direction
            }
            $row++
        } `
    | group-object Direction, Priority `
    | where-object { $_.Count -gt 1 }

# render the duplicates for display
$duplicates `
    | foreach-object { $_.Group } `
    | sort-object Row `
    | format-table
```

output:

```
 Priority Name       Direction
--- -------- ----       ---------
  2 10       ad-rule    Inbound
  5 10       ad-rule-10 Inbound
  9 :        :          Inbound
 10 :        :          Inbound
```

This format doesn't necessarily tell you what row each item is a duplicate of, so if there's a long list it might not be clear what needs to be changed to remove duplicates. In that case, you might find it more useful to list the *sets* of duplicates like this:

```
$duplicates | foreach-object {
    [pscustomobject] @{
        "Priority"  = $_.Group[0].Priority
        "Direction" = $_.Group[0].Direction
        "Rows"      = $_.Group.Row -join ", "
    }
} | sort-object Direction, Priority | format-table
```

which now outputs the following:

```
Priority Direction Rows
-------- --------- ----
:        Inbound   9, 10
10       Inbound   2, 5
```

and you can see rows 9 and 10 are duplicates of each other, and so are rows 2 and 5.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$data = @'
Priority,Name,Direction
10,ad-rule,Inbound
20,ftp-rule,Inbound
30,dummy-rule,Inbound
10,ad-rule-10,Inbound
40,ad-rule,Inbound
50,ad-rule-50,Inbound
60,ad-rule-60,Inbound
:,:,Inbound
:,:,Inbound
990,,Inbound
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv
$dups, $rows = @{}.GetType()::new([Collections.StructuralComparisons]::StructuralEqualityComparer), 2
$data | ForEach-Object { $dups.($_.priority, $_.direction) += @($rows++) }
$dups.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { $_.Value.Length -gt 1 } | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Result:

```
Name          Value
----          -----
{10, Inbound} {2, 5}
{:, Inbound}  {9, 10}
```