# Converting line breaks to commas in excel sheet using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, newline, line-breaks

I am working on powershell code to check each column in all rows in the excel spreadsheet and check if any line breaks are exist and convert them into commas. I have tried with below code but it is not updating the line breaks into commas.

Code:

```
# Load the Excel file
$path = "./NSG_Rules.xlsx"
$exceldata = Import-Excel -Path $path

# Iterate through each cell and replace line breaks with commas if present

`foreach ($row in $exceldata) {     foreach ($property in $row.psobject.Properties) {         # Check if the cell content has line breaks and replace them with commas         if ($property.Value -match "`r`n") {             $property.Value = $property.Value -replace "`r`n", ","         }     } }`

# Save the updated workbook.

$rows | Export-Excel $exceldata
```

My requirement is, I have excel spread sheet and it is having many rows and columns. the powershell code needs to check each cell in the excel spread sheet and if any line breaks(refer screenshot) found then it needs to convert it into commas and update the excel sheet.

In the uploaded image screenshot, the highlighted red color cell is having the line break. so it needs to convert into single line with comma like below:
I have tried below code but it is not updating the excel spread sheet by removing the line breaks and converting them into comma.

Screenshots for reference:
Present format:
[image]
Required outputformat:
[image]

Comment: That's not a line break - the horizontal line between the two IP addresses is a *cell border* - the two values are in different cells. If you look at the screenshot in this question (which seems to be asking about the same spreadsheet) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77751324/displaying-wrong-duplicated-row-numbers - you can see the first 6 columns in the first row of data are merged across rows 2 and 3, but the DestinationAddressPrefix column is *not* merged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton) points out:

- you're *not* dealing with newlines (line breaks) *inside cells* (if you were, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77748624/45375) would help you).
- you're dealing with "overflow rows", where what is *conceptually* an additional cell value is actually contained in a separate row, i.e. in an additional cell *below* the cell of interest (with the other cells in a row of interest *merged* with their empty counterparts below).

---

To append these "overflow values" to their corresponding main-row values, you can use the following approach:

- Process rows *conditionally*, depending on whether they are "main" or "overflow" rows.
- Detect the latter by whether their *first* cell is *empty*.
- Among the remaining cells, append any non-empty values to their main-row counterparts.

**Important**:

- In order to be able to save changes to a workbook, it mustn't currently be open in Excel. You can ensure this manually or - assuming you're comfortable doing so - can automatically forcefully terminate any running Excel processes to ensure that saving succeeds, by adding the `-KillExcel` switch to the `Export-Excel` calls below.
- The solution below uses [`Export-Excel`](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/blob/master/mdHelp/en/export-excel.md)'s `-ClearSheet` switch to *re-create* the worksheet's data, which has two implications:

  - **All formatting is lost**; see the **next section** for a - more cumbersome - **solution that *preserves* formatting**.
  - If the workbook happened to have *multiple* sheets, the re-created sheet is placed *last* (arguably, this shouldn't happen); the `-MoveToStart` switch used below compensates for that.
- *Not* using `-ClearSheet` isn't an option (without substantial additional effort that may require use of the `Excel.Application` COM Automation server instead), because:

  - Fundamentally, `Export-Excel` doesn't *replace* a worksheet's content, but simply *updates* it, with *any preexisting formatting*  *retained as-is*, as well as *any content unaffected by the update*.
  - While you *could* - somewhat - compensate for the reduction in the count of rows due to the described processing - by appending additional, *empty*, rows that blank out the extra original ones, which requires passing objects that contain *empty* strings for each target column -  *merged* cells present in the original worksheet would then effectively *hide* values. See the next section for a solution that requires more work.

```bash
$path = "./NSG_Rules.xlsx"

$rows = Import-Excel $path

# Get the column (property) names, split into the first and all remaining ones.
$firstPropName, $remainingPropNames = $rows[0].psobject.Properties.Name

# Process all rows, merging the cells of "overflow" rows with the
# corresponding cells of the main rows.
$modifiedRows = 
  & {
    foreach ($row in $rows) {
      if ($null -eq $row.$firstPropName) { # an "overflow" row
        # Process all remaining columns and, for any that contain a value, append that
        # value to the most recent "main" row's corresponding column values.
        foreach ($propName in $remainingPropNames) {
          if ($null -ne ($val = $row.$propName)) {
            # Note: For appending to succeed, the main row's
            #       value must be converted to a string, if necessary.
            $prevRow.$propName = [string] $prevRow.$propName + ',' + $val
          }
        }
      } else { # a "main" row - possibly complete by itself, possibly complemented by subsequent rows.
        if ($prevRow) { $prevRow } # Output, if a previous row is now by definition complete.
        # Save this row - its column values may need to be appended to in the next iteration(s).
        $prevRow = $row
      }
    }
    # Output the last row, if necessary.
    if ($prevRow) { $prevRow }
  }

# Export the modified rows back to the workbook,
# re-creating the sheet - without formatting - in the process.
$modifiedRows | Export-Excel -ClearSheet -MoveToStart $path
```

---

##### Solution that preserves formatting:

Such a solution requires a *two-pass* approach:

- First, update the cells in the "main" rows only; leave the "overflow" rows alone, but record their row indices in a list for later removal.
- Then, via `Export-Excel -PassThru` - which is equivalent to calling `Export-Excel` (to write the updated values) followed by [`Open-ExcelPackage`](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/blob/master/mdHelp/en/open-excelpackage.md) - obtain a reference to the Excel package (workbook) for advanced operations, which allows removal (deletion) of rows directly from the spreadsheet.

```bash
$path = "./NSG_Rules.xlsx"
$rows = Import-Excel $path

# Get the column (property) names, split into the first and all remaining ones.
$firstPropName, $remainingPropNames = $rows[0].psobject.Properties.Name

$rowsToDeleteIndices = [System.Collections.Generic.List[int]] @()

# Process all rows, merging the cells of "overflow" rows with the
# corresponding cells of the main rows.
$rowIndex = 1 # Start with 1, to account for the header row. 
foreach ($row in $rows) {
  ++$rowIndex
  if ($null -eq $row.$firstPropName) {
    # an "overflow" row
    # Process all remaining columns and, for any that contain a value, append that
    # value to the most recent "main" row's corresponding column values.
    foreach ($propName in $remainingPropNames) {
      if ($null -ne ($val = $row.$propName)) {
        # Note: For appending to succeed, the main row's
        #       value must be converted to a string, if necessary.
        $prevMainRow.$propName = [string] $prevMainRow.$propName + ',' + $val
      }
    }
    # Leave the overflow rows alone for now, but record 
    # their (1-based) indices for later deletion.
    $rowsToDeleteIndices.Add($rowIndex) 
  }
  else {
    # a "main" row - possibly complete by itself, possibly complemented by subsequent rows.
    # Save this row - its column values may need to be appended to in the next iteration(s).
    $prevMainRow = $row
  }
}

# Export the modified values back to the worksheet, 
# in place, with all formatting preserved.
# Via -PassThru, obtain a reference to the package (workbook),
# for advanced operations such as row deletion.
$pkg = $rows | Export-Excel $path -PassThru

# Obtain a reference to the first worksheet again
# (the same one implicitly targeted by Import-Excel / Export-Excel).
$ws = $pkg.Workbook.Worksheets[1]

# Now delete the no longer needed overflow rows from it.
$i = 0
$rowsToDeleteIndices | ForEach-Object { $ws.DeleteRow($_ + $i--) }

# Close and thereby implicitly save the package.
Close-ExcelPackage $pkg
```

Comment: Hi @mklement0. Thanks for your quick reply and the code. I have tried testing the above code but getting below error:
Cannot convert value ",21" to type "System.Double". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: @NaniN: That implies that the main-row value was a number (`[double]` aka `System.Double`), so the `+=` operation fails. You can work around that by converting the value to a string first (though whether that's appropriate for your data is for you to decide) - please see the updated answer.

Comment: Hi @mklement0. Thank you so much for the update code. I have tested the code and it is working fine. But the format of the excel sheet is changing to normal and old format of the sheet is not coming in the re-created sheet.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, @NaniN. I have since added a solution that preserves the original formatting (which requires quite a bit more effort).

Comment: Thanks for the updated code @mklement0. I have tested the code which you have mentioned but it is throwing below error:
Exception calling "Save" with "0" argument(s): "Error saving file C:\Users\madamaneril\powershell\NSG_Rules.xlsx"

Comment: @NaniN: That implies that you have the workbook open in Excel. In order to be able to save changes to a workbook, it mustn't currently be open in Excel. You can ensure this manually or - assuming you're comfortable doing so - can automatically forcefully terminate any running Excel processes to ensure that saving succeeds, by adding the `-KillExcel` switch to the `Export-Excel` calls. I've also added this information to the answer.

Comment: Hi @mklement0. Thanks for your updated code. but there is small change in the requirement. This time the  excel spread sheet doesn't have overflows rows. we have few merged columns (updated the screenshot in the question). I have tried updating the code but it is updating only single IP address in the spread sheet. Kindly help me to fix this issue. Please let me know if needs to raise new question for this change.